# Wagtail customize PageChooserPanel page explorer view

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I’m looking for a way to customize the Explorer that pops-up when using the PageChooserPanel, ideally I would like to add two more columns there.
I’ve found this http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.2/reference/hooks.html#choosers but that only covers generating a custom queryset not adding columns, is that even possible?

Alternatively I can live with only changing the default title shown on the pagechooserpanel explorer but so far adding a `__str__` method to the class hasn’t worked

Here a graphic representation to my question

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the displayed title by overriding your page model's `get_admin_display_title` method:

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_admin_display_title

Comment: Amazing thanks for your prompt answer, one more thing. I have noticed that the search in the page explorer only searches on the original draft_title field and not in the new generated title. Is there a way to change the search behaviour?

Comment: Adding `get_admin_display_title` (or whatever field/method is most appropriate) to `search_fields` as documented at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/search/indexing.html#indexing-callables-and-other-attributes should do it, although you may need to switch to a 'real' search backend such as Elasticsearch or PostgreSQL search rather than the default database implementation.